# Continous Integration with ASP.NET MVC and TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. This application is hosted in TFS. I have setup a build server. When a checkin happens, my code is complied and dropped in a folder on my test server. The drop folder is an IIS application folder. The goal is when a user visits `http://[myTestServer]/MyProject`, they should see the latest compiled version of the app. In an attempt to do this, I'm dropping files in `//[myTestServer]/c$/inetpub/www/myProject/`. However, I'm getting more than I bargained for.

I've noticed that the build server puts a bunch of assemblies and creates 2 directories: _PublishedWebsites and logs. _PublishedWebsites contains two directories: MyProjectName and MyProjectName_Package. From what I can tell MyProjectName contains the files that I want put in //[myTestServer]/c$/inetpub/www/myProject/. What am I doing wrong?

How do I setup it up such that when a user visits http://[myTestServer]/MyProject, they see the latest compiled version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Microsoft's [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) for deployment of Web applications and Web sites to IIS servers.

This tutorial describes in detail how to configure TFS for Web Deployment:

- [Configuring Team Foundation Server for Web Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment)

  - [Creating a Team Project in TFS](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/creating-a-team-project-in-tfs)
  - [Adding Content to Source Control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/adding-content-to-source-control)
  - [Configuring a TFS Build Server for Web Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-tfs-build-server-for-web-deployment)
  - [Creating a Build Definition That Supports Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/creating-a-build-definition-that-supports-deployment)
  - [Deploying a Specific Build](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/deploying-a-specific-build)
  - [Configuring Permissions for Team Build Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/configuring-permissions-for-team-build-deployment)